# What does local host : 8888 token in jupyter notebook mean in layman terms? http://localhost:8888/?token=f----

Tags: jupyter-notebook

What does local host : 8888 token in jupyter notebook mean in layman's terms? Who is client and which is remote server. What if  I change the port number? What does token service mean

Comment: If you're asking about the token, that's probably a hashed key that's sent in the URL as an identifier. The answer below is correct when talking about the use of localhost when self-hosting a webserver. You'll also see 127.0.0.1, which is entirely interchangeable with localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does your browser get to know which server is the server you are looking for, e.g. you try to search amazon.in: how does you browser know to give you the website you are looking for?

There is something called DNS server which converts your domain name into IP address and then your browser gets to know the exact server, in a same way local host is the server which refers to your own computer via loopback network interface.

It is possible to launch the application on local host for testing purposes.

If you access “http://localhost” in the browser, the request will not be forwarded to the internet, but (usually) to the local loopback network interface. Typically, localhost has the IP address 127.0.0.1. This refers back to your own machine.